# Desktop theme for Android tablets

Tags: magento-1.7, mobile, exception

I am using a separate theme for mobile devices but I still want to present the desktop theme for Android tablets.

here's my matched expressions for the exception

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

and in iPad it shows the desktop theme as it should but on Android tablets i'm still getting the mobile theme.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the user agent string for Android Tablets contained "Safari" whereas the string for Android cell phones has "Mobile Safari" so I just targeted "Mobile Safari" for my mobile theme and now all tablets get the desktop theme.

Here's my final string to target only mobile devices, not tablets

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Mobile Safari|Opera Mini
```

Notice that I removed "Android" from that string.